# DevExpress XtraSpellChecker randomly stops working, shows all words as mis-spelled

Tags: c#, devexpress

We recently released a desktop record keeping product that required a simple spell checker on a couple text box fields.  We use DevExpress 10.1 XtraSpellChecker.  It does exactly what we need but customers report that occasionally it simply stops working and shows all words as being mis-spelled.

My guess is that it cannot open the dictionary but I have no clue as to why.  Typically stopping and restarting the program solves the problem.

Most instances of this error occur on computers with single users who have full modify rights on the installation folder ( location of dictionary ).

Anyone experience the same thing, have ideas of what might be causing this?  Search of DevExpress forum has proven fruitless.  It does happen on more than one installation but several have reported no issues.

Oh, and we are using it in Spell As You Type mode.

Comment: Did you report this to DevExpress support? I can't say I've heard of this happening before, but they may have some ideas. (I'd love to hand over all DevExpress support to StackOverflow but I don't think it would fly :) ). Cheers, Julian, CTO.

Comment: I couldn't, then prompted by your post I looked again and realized I was logged in with personal registration as opposed to the email linked to our licensed copy.  So yes, I just posted it.  Thanks for the follow up.  Really dig the DevExpress tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The check as you type mode works by checking the text in a background thread.  Such a situation can occur if an exception is raised in the background thread that terminates it.  Try to include a handler to all exceptions raised in your app and ask your users to send you the log when this problem occurs.  To learn how to catch exceptions in all threads, please refer to the code snippet posted in the

[Application.ThreadException Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx)  MSDN article.